# Count number of objects created from a class

Tags: c++

I would like to achieve a functionality where I can know how much object where created using a specific class.

I have tried the following:

**myClass.h**

```
class myClass {
private:
    static int internalCounter;
    int id;
public:
    myClass(): id(internalCounter) {internalCounter++;}
}
```

The problem is that C++ doesn't allow this, and I'm not sure how to workaround this.
I have seen similar question in SA in which answer suggested something like:

```
myClass::internalCounter = 0;
```

But I don't think this right on the syntax level.

Comment: What do you mean by "does now allow this"?!

Comment: @duffymo: It looks like a unique identifier for each object, rather than a reference count.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: Rescinding the close.

Comment: because it's not clear what you are really asking. Aside from not having a semi-colon at the end of your class and a potential link error, the basics of what you are doing is legal in C++ even if not the solution to what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

C++ *does* allow this. But the static variable needs a definition, and it sounds like that's missing. You'll need to put this in a source file (not the header)

```
int myClass::internalCounter = 0;
```

The `= 0` is optional, since static variables are zero-initialised by default, but you might prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your static variable as

```
int myClass::internalCounter = 0;
```

in an implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

The other suggestion you saw was almost right. You need something like this:

```
int myClass::internalCounter = 0;
```

But it needs to go in a **source file** (*.cpp) rather than a header. That line is necessary because the declaration on its own (in the header file) would never be instantiated otherwise. Resolving it in a source file means it will get picked up and instantiated within a specific translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

You must define your static variable:

```
 int myClass::internalCounter=0;
```

in your implementation file, its always best to read your compiler/linker output, in case of g++ it is:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2): undefined reference to `myClass::internalCounter'
```

`undefined reference` means it was not defined, this is a hint on what you must fix in your code

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that, as you need to put your counter into a source file anyway, you take the definition of it out of the class and just put it into the anonymous namespace area. That takes some of the implementation detail of your class out of your header file.

If you are working in C++11 use `atomic_int` rather than `int`.

Use post-increment operator to make the action properly atomic.

**myClass.h**

```
class myClass
{
  private:
    int id;

  public:
    myClass();
   // etc
};
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
#include <atomic>
#include "myClass.h" 

namespace { 
   static std::atomic_int internalCounter;
}

myClass::myClass()
   : id( internalCounter++ )
{
}
```

the `operator++` post-increment on atomic_int is, at the name suggests, atomic, so it will be thread-safe.